# Summarize if-loop in the right way

Tags: javascript, jquery

the Javascript code I wrote is for the shopping cart of a small shop site. I know that this code is very ugly and I tried to summarize it with argument handover in functions but I didn´t come to a conclusion that works. What is the best way to shorten this code?

Thanks a lot!

Javascript:

```
var pack = '#writePackSummary';
var netPriceOutput = '.writeNetPriceSummary';
var taxPriceOutput = '#writeTaxPriceSummary';
var grossPriceOutput = '#writeGrossPriceSummary'
var netPrice1 = 25;
var netPrice3 = 45.55;
var netPrice6 = 89.10;
var tax = 0.19;

if ($(pack).text() == '1') {
    $(netPriceOutput).text(netPrice1.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\./g, ','));
    $(taxPriceOutput).text((netPrice1*tax).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\./g, ','));
    $(grossPriceOutput).text(((netPrice1*tax)+netPrice1).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\./g, ','));
} else if ($(pack).text() == '3') {
    $(netPriceOutput).text(netPrice3.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\./g, ','));
    $(taxPriceOutput).text((netPrice3*tax).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\./g, ','));
    $(grossPriceOutput).text(((netPrice3*tax)+netPrice3).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\./g, ','));
} else if ($(pack).text() == '6') {
    $(netPriceOutput).text(netPrice6.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\./g, ','));
    $(taxPriceOutput).text((netPrice6*tax).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\./g, ','));
    $(grossPriceOutput).text(((netPrice6*tax)+netPrice6).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\./g, ','));
};
```

Comment: You could use an array `netPrice` instead of three different variables, then reference `netPrice[val]` just once. However, "best" in this case is largely a matter of opinion and this is not a good question for SO.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist perhaps he's trying to learn as he goes?  Have you ever thought of that?

Comment: Do you expect to get the behavior of == '3' when the value is 4 or 5?  In your current logic it will only hit the exact values of 1, 3, or 6 and do nothing for other values.  Are they possible values, and what should happen if they are?

Comment: @RalphCaraveo There are many hundreds of existing shopping cart implementations on the web in almost every language and web framework imaginable. Building possibly mission critical software that may handle credit card and other financially sensitive data (opening companies up to massive liability if implemented insecurely) is not something to be attempting if you're just starting out learning to code.

Comment: Assuming this is more of a learning exercise, as a general rule you would want to separate the calculations (which only involve numbers) from the extraction and formatting code.

Comment: Instead of replacing the '.' with ',', you should look into using [.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: @MattPileggi the values 1,3,6 are months. So we have 1,3,6 month subscription packets. I thought about using 1,2,3... instead of the months. If that would make the code shorter its a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to unify the logic first. Find parts which maybe could get wrapped into a function or use that linear code and read different data based on a selection.

For example:

```
var pack = '#writePackSummary';
var netPriceOutput = '.writeNetPriceSummary';
var taxPriceOutput = '#writeTaxPriceSummary';
var grossPriceOutput = '#writeGrossPriceSummary'

/* declare the prices as array */
var netPrice = {
    1: 25,
    2: 45.55,
    6: 89.10,
};

var tax = 0.19;

/* read the input only once from the element */
var packNr = parseInt( $( pack ).text() );

/* test if a value dataset exists */
if( netPrice[packNr] ) {

    $( netPriceOutput ).text( netPrice[packNr].toFixed(2).toString().replace( /\./g, ',' ) );
    $( taxPriceOutput ).text( (netPrice[packNr]*tax).toFixed(2).toString().replace( /\./g, ',' ) );
    $( grossPriceOutput ).text( ((netPrice[packNr]*tax)+netPrice[packNr]).toFixed(2).toString().replace( /\./g, ',' ) );
}
```

That would replace three `if` conditions with just one and allows to quickly add other prices.

Go further by identifying more parts of the code that are duplicates of each other and combine the logic in reusable parts (i.e. functions/methods). For example the answer of Scimonster could be the next step.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you could replace all of those `.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\./g, ',')` with a single function:

```
function stringNum(num) {return num.toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ',')}

if ($(pack).text() == '1') {
    $(netPriceOutput).text(stringNum(netPrice1));
    $(taxPriceOutput).text(stringNum(netPrice1*tax));
    $(grossPriceOutput).text(stringNum((netPrice1*tax)+netPrice1));
} etc...
```

Maybe consider using a `switch` construct instead of multiple if-elses? This is also faster, as it doesn't recreate the jQuery object each time.

Comment: toFixed() already converts to a string, so there is no need to also call toString().

Comment: Also, you would want to cache the value of $(pack).text() so that you don't have to recreate the jQuery collection object for each conditional.

Comment: Maybe replace "num.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\./g,',')" with "num.toLocaleString().toFixed(2)".

Comment: @Jack `toLocaleString()` isn't guaranteed to give the format that the OP wants. You're right about `toFixed()` casting to string.